# CCLayerColor curious background apperance

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I inherit a class named FinishedLevelLayer from CCLayerColor and declare an empty init. in my class i declare a CCMenu, but when i show the menu, i get a weird black background for the layer. The background isn't full screen. How can i avoid this?

Also, i try to animate the menu (make it fade in) but it doesn't work. Here is the code for this:

```
        finishMenu.visible = true;
        [finishMenu setOpacity:0];
        id fade = [CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.35f];
        id sec = [CCSequence actions:fade, nil];
        [finishMenu runAction:sec];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean under "empty init"? if your class is subclass of CCLayerColor, create it's instance with layerWithColor: method. what items are in your menu?